# adding permissions with visudo to a linux user for using wireshark

Tags: sudo, wireshark, sudoers

Im trying to set permissions for a user named 'invitado', jus for some binaries: wireshark, tcpdump and traceroute. Iv done according to the sudoers syntax which i think is the following:

```
# /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

Defaults    env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
ldac    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
# (Note that later entries override this, so you might need to move
# it further down)
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
#
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

#Permiso de SUDO a guest de wireshark
invitado ALL=NOPASSWD : /usr/bin/aptitude/usr/bin/X11/wireshark
invitado ALL=NOPASSWD : /usr/bin/wireshark
invitado ALL=NOPASSWD : /usr/sbin/traceroute
invitado ALL=NOPASSWD : /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

However, i keep obtaining the same visudo error output:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 30 <<<
What now? Options are:
  (e)dit sudoers file again
  e(x)it without saving changes to sudoers file
  (Q)uit and save changes to sudoers file (DANGER!)
```

Any suggestions??? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try removing the spaces after NOPASSWD. Also, you can put all the commands on one line.

```
invitado ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/aptitude, /usr/bin/X11/wireshark, /usr/bin/wireshark, /usr/sbin/traceroute, /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

**Edit:**
 Also, I think `/usr/bin/aptitude/usr/bin/X11/wireshark` was probably wrong. That should be 2 commands, `/usr/bin/aptitude` and `/usr/bin/X11/wireshark`.

Comment: You were right, that line contains two commands. I've tried commenting the aptitude (im not interested in giving permissions for aptitude), putting all the commands in one line and got the same message: `>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 28 <<<
What now?`

Comment: Did you remove the space after NOPASSWD (before the :)?

Comment: I got it! i think the error was because of where i was placing the permissions line in the document... i think it sould be before the groups section. The working file is: `...ldac ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    invitado ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/X11/wireshark, /usr/bin/wireshark, /usr/sbin/traceroute, /usr/sbin/tcpdump...` Anyway, thanks to [ithcy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/59461/ithcy) for answering and helping

Comment: Ah... i was about to suggest `ALL=(ALL)` :) glad you got it working.